# how to scale all controls equally with high resolution display setting?

Tags: unity, resolution, display, scaling

I've had some success using Unity on a high resolution display (mac retina) by adjusting the 'Scale for menu and title bars' ratio (see image below); however, some of the icons (including sliders and checkboxes, see image again) are not scaling, while others (including buttons and drop downs) are. Is there any way to increase the size of all controls equally? Thanks.

[image: image with tiny controls]

Comment: For the launcher you can adjust the icons size in [the appearance settings](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Screen-Shot-2012-04-26-at-13.42.jpg)

Comment: @Wilf the launcher icons are scaling in accordance with the 'scale for menu and title bars' setting under Displays so I'm good there, thanks.

Comment: This is also a big issue in chrome, when I set the scaling to 2.0 I cannot use the menues any more: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ISC0B.png